# How to put parameters in actionPerformed method when using listeners

Tags: java, parameters, action, listener

Say if I created a new class and put a JButton that I want to effect something else on the screen. However, that thing is somewhere else in a different class. How would I add some sort of parameter to the actionPerformed method? Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class button2 implements ActionListener{
  public void buttton2(final Screen screen){
    JButton test = new JButton("Hello");
    test.addActionListener(this);
  }

      //How do I add a parameter in here?
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0, Screen screen) {
    screen.repaint();

  }


}
```

or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Store the screen in a field:

```
public class Button2 implements ActionListener{

    private Screen screen;

    public Button2(final Screen screen) {
        this.screen = screen;
        JButton test = new JButton("Hello");
        test.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        screen.repaint();
    }
}
```